# Commit despite raising custom exception in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to display an alert whenever a new record has been inserted into a table. To communicate that new data has been inserted, I'm raising a custom exception. However, I'm finding that the commit doesn't complete successfully whenever the custom exception is raised. Is it possible to force it to complete despite the exception, or is there a better, alternative way to do this?

```
@event.listens_for(Session, "after_flush")
def after_flush(session, flush_context):
    for instance in session.new:
        if hasattr(instance, "on_insert"):
            instance.on_insert(session)
```

Below is committed fine if I don't raise the custom exception

```
    def on_insert(self, session):
        # Removed code which utilises the passed in session, as such after_insert event hook is probably not going to be suitable
        session.commit() # Leads to ResourceClosedError which rolls back the transaction
        raise NewClientError(f"{self.__repr__()}")
        #pass
```

Because the above on_insert is run within a parent transaction, executing commit() again eventually leads to ResourceClosedError which rolls back the parent transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked around this by raising the custom exception as part of the after_commit event hook using:

https://gist.github.com/letmaik/b296b02e730cd4c469bf
and [How do I get SQLAlchemy objects after commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896385/how-do-i-get-sqlalchemy-objects-after-commit)

In my case I've just modified the on_insert function to register a listener for after_commit:

```
    def on_insert(self, session):
        event.listen(session, "after_commit", self.__raise_alert)
```

This now calls __raise_alert after the transaction is completed, hence it doesn't lead to a rollback.